# Scrapy - ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

When writing command "scrapy crawl weather_spider2 -o output.json", I got error
[scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests

and then ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
I read some article in stakoverflow, and try to fix but it not help

My code:

```
import scrapy
import re
from weather_parent.weather_spider.items import WeatherItem

class WeatherSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "weather_spider2"
    allowed_domains = 'https://weather.com'
    start_urls = ['https://weather.com/en-MT/weather/today/l/bf01d09009561812f3f95abece23d16e123d8c08fd0b8ec7ffc9215c0154913c']
    
    def parse_url(self, response):
        city = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"location")].text()').get()
        temp = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="TemperatureValue"]/text()').get()
        air_quality = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="AirQualityCategory"]/text()').get()
        cond = response.xpath('//div[@data-testid="wxPhrase"]/text()').get()

        item = WeatherItem()
        item["city"] = city
        item["temp"] = temp
        item["air_quality"] = air_quality
        item["cond"] = cond
        yield item
```

error

```
[]
2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened

2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023

2021-10-25 22:07:39 **[scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\weather_parent\weather_spider\spiders\crawl_weather.py", line 12, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback= self.parse_url)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 73, in _set_url
    raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')

**ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h**

2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.015959,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 15, 7, 39, 874679),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 15, 7, 39, 858720)}
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\weather_parent\weather_spider\spiders\crawl_weather.py", line 12, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback= self.parse_url)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 73, in _set_url
    raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-10-25 22:07:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.015959,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 15, 7, 39, 874679),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 15, 7, 39, 858720)}
```

Comment: `allowed_domains` has letter `s` at the end so it expects many elements and it means it should be a list. If you put single string then it treats it also as list and you get list of chars - `['h', 't', 't', 'p', 's', ...]` (see `list('https://weather.com')`) - and this can gives `ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h`

Answer (score 1):

Rename your parse_url function to  parse this is the default callback used by Scrapy to process downloaded responses, when their requests don’t specify a callback.
the city xpath was wrong just use `/text()`. in allowed_domains, Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, then add 'example.com' to the list. it will be list. nothing else every thing is ok.

```
from scrapy.crawler  import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
import re
# from weather_parent.weather_spider.items import WeatherItem

class WeatherSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "weather_spider2"
    allowed_domains = 'https://weather.com'
    start_urls = ['https://weather.com/en-MT/weather/today/l/bf01d09009561812f3f95abece23d16e123d8c08fd0b8ec7ffc9215c0154913c']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        city = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"location")]/text()').get()
        temp = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="TemperatureValue"]/text()').get()
        air_quality = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="AirQualityCategory"]/text()').get()
        cond = response.xpath('//div[@data-testid="wxPhrase"]/text()').get()

        item = {}
        item["city"] = city
        item["temp"] = temp
        item["air_quality"] = air_quality
        item["cond"] = cond
        yield item

# 
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(WeatherSpiderSpider)
process.start()
```

### output

```
{'city': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India Weather', 'temp': '29�', 'air_quality': 'Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups', 'cond': 'Partly Cloudy'}
```

Comment: tks @Samsul Islam . I used your fixed code above, and when I run, it's got another error "raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable" . And can I run without CrawlProcess() part?

Comment: have you run it in command line like python spider.py file name? If you are in scrapy project you do not need CrawlProcess() part

Comment: I run from scrapy project dir as "PS D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\weather_parent> scrapy crawl weather_spider2 -o output.json"  weather _parent is folder that contain scrapy.cfg  file

Comment: Yes, its ok. you have to delete crawlerProcess. Now you are getting error. chage     allowed_domains = 'https://weather.com' to     allowed_domains = ['weather.com']. I think it should work.

Comment: allowed_domains = ['weather.com'] . and no CrawlerProcess (). I run "PS D:\ca nhan\Anaconda\weather_parent> scrapy crawl weather_spider2 -o output.json" . Error " raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable"

Comment: may be another problem. I can not found it, you may try to create scrapy project newly.